# mat-horizontal-stepper steps going out of view

Tags: angular-material

I am using Mat-Horizontal-stepper and I have more than 12 steps. I am rendering the stepper in Mat-Card component. The issue is that mat stepper steps are going out of card container and causing horizontal scroll. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `mat-horizontal-stepper` by `<mat-vertical-stepper>`, that way won't have problems with horizontal overflow.

In other case you can try to add some styles to the class `.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container`

Comment: When i am adding additional style to .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container , its not reflecting in my view!